# Cheating in multiple choice tests.

Tags: probability

What is the probability that in a multiple choice test exam session, where $k$ people took the test (that contains $n$ questions with 2 possible answers each and where *exactly* one answer to each question is the correct one) cheating has occurred, i.e. there exists *at least* two tests that are identical ?

My solution is $$1-\frac{\binom{2^{n}}{k}}{\binom{2^{n}+k-1}{k}},$$ since there are $2^n$ possible tests and the set of all multisets with $k$ elements from $2^n$ is the size of all possible "exam sessions". For the numerator I counted only those exam sessions where cheating didn't occur, i.e. all tests are different from eachother. Since what I'm looking for is the complement of this set I get the above.

Comment: If two students get all of them right, does that mean they cheated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not reasonable to consider two identical tests as evidence of cheating. And people do not choose answers at random. So let us reword the problem as follows.

We have $k$ people who each toss a fair coin $n$ times. What is the probability that at least two of them will get identical sequences of heads and tails?

The required probability  $1$ minus the probability that the sequences are **all different**. We go after that probability.

There are $2^n$ possible sequences of length $n$ made up of H and/or T. In order to make typing easier, and also not to get confused, let's call this number $N$. So each of our $k$ people independently produces one of these $N$ sequences.

Write down the sequences chosen by the various people, listed in order of student ID. There are $N^k$ equally likely possibilities.

Now we count the number of ways to obtain a list of $k$ *distinct* sequences. This is $N(N-1)(N-2)\cdots (N-k+1)$. So the probability the sequences are all different is 
$$\frac{N(N-1)(N-2) \cdots (N-k+1)}{N^k}.\tag{A}$$
So the answer to the original problem is $1$ minus the expression in (A).

The numerator can be written in various other ways, for example as $k!\dbinom{N}{k}$.

**Remark:** I prefer to think of this in elementary Birthday Problem terms. The probability that the sequence obtained by Student $2$ is different from the one obtained by Student $1$ is $\frac{N-1}{N}$. **Given** that fact, the probability that the sequence obtained by Student $3$ is different from both of the first two sequences is $\frac{N-2}{N}$. And so on. So the probability in (A) can be thought of as
$$\frac{N-1}{N}\cdot\frac{N-2}{N}\cdots \frac{N-k+1}{N}.$$

Comment: I think I see what your about, but let me be the devils advocate, in order to understand your answer better: Doesn't your wording change the problem ? In the way you put it, order matters (so you use $N^k$ instead of $\binom{N+k-1}{k}$ and $k!\binom{N}{k}$ instead of $\binom{N}{k}$). So what happens, if a person grading the tests has in front of him the $k$ tests which he has to evaluate, and he chooses not to look at the names/IDs of the students (a process by which we "loose" the order) and only compares the tests to see if there are a "cheat tests" ?

Comment: For the **computation** of the probability, order does not matter. The problem with not using order in this problem is that the events you counted in your denominator are not equally likely. For $n$ of any not too tiny size, this will make almost no practical difference, your formula and mine will, to high accuracy, give essentially the same numerical answers. However, the one in the answer is technically dead on.